# Ubuntu 14.04 - Can't use newest OpenGL version

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, opengl

I'm running Xubuntu 14.04 LTS on a laptop with an Nvidia GeForce GTX 765m with the nvidia-340 drivers from the xorg-edgers PPA. I'm trying to run an application that requires a recent version of OpenGL, but all that's detected on my system is OpenGL version 1.4 (the 765m should support up to 4.5):

```
$>> sudo prime-select nvidia
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-340/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-340/alt_ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in manual mode
$>> glxinfo | grep version  
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4
OpenGL version string: 1.4 (3.0 Mesa 10.6.0-rc2)
```

When I switch to the Intel chip, a different version is detected (however the application I'm trying to run needs the Nvidia GPU):

```
$>> sudo prime-select intel                                                      
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-340-prime/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-340-prime/alt_ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in manual mode
$>> glxinfo | grep version
server glx version string: 1.4
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 10.6.0-rc2
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.6.0-rc2
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
```

I've tried purging and reinstalling the nvidia drivers several times (and tried several different versions) to no avail. My understanding was that the nvidia drivers should provide an OpenGL implementation >= 3.0, but I can't seem to get it recognized. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.